# Android Submenu, how to go back to main menu?

Tags: android, submenu

I use an xml to for my ContextMenu, which is like :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item android:id="@+id/Ordermenu" android:title="Order">
    <menu android:id="@+id/OrderBySubMenu">
      <item android:id="@+id/OrderByASC" android:title="Order ASC"   /> 
      <item android:id="@+id/OrderByDESC" android:title="Order DESC"  />
      <item android:id="@+id/Cancel" android:title="Cancel"  />
    </menu>
   </item> 
 <item android:id="@+id/ActionAmenu" android:title="Action A"/>
</menu>
```

I use following code to display the menu, in my onCreateContextMenu

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.layout.my menu, menu);
```

I manage option click with following code :

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.Displaymenu:
     //do stuff
     return true;
  case R.id.OrderByASC:
     //do stuff
     return true;
  case R.id.OrderByDESC:
     //do stuff
     return true;
  default :
     return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Starting the Context Menu it display Two options:

- Order
- Action A

Clicking on Order show a submenu :

- Order ASC
- Order DESC
- Cancel

Now, If the user click on cancel (or click on the hardware back button), no action is specified, so it call super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) which go back to my main activity.

How can I manage to go back to the main menu in such case? i.e. diplay the initial :

- Order
- Action A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked only by adding :

```
case R.id.Cancel:
   openContextMenu(findViewById(selected_view_id));
   return true;
```

in public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)

selected_view_id is stored by

```
selected_view_id=v.getId();
```

in onCreateContextMenu

Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this long ago but i think you will have to override onPrepareOptionsMenu as well to get this to work. This is called before it shows, and you will have to put flags here on what items to show for the user.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Clear the previous layout
    menu.clear();

    if(showMainMenu) 
    {
        // Add main menu items..
        menu.add(0, R.id.ordermenu, 0, "True");
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Add sub-menu items
        menu.add(0, R.id.ordermenuASC, 0, "True");
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

So when user clicks a main menu item, change the boolean flag a redo the process.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me even if it's not what I'm doing finally... I was trying to implement your solution and I was asking where to set the ShowMainMenu value, but I finally managed to do what I want only adding a few line is the oncontextmenuselected : please see my own answer.
Anyway, your solution is maybe more adapted for sub-sub menus and so on...